# Knitr dropping records

Tags: r, knitr

I have a R package that was inherited after a person left.  I realized after working through the file and code that the knitr file that is produced is dropping the last few records on the html table that's being built.
The problem:
the code is getting data in chunks of 10 records and then producing the table.  I need to figure out how to get the remaining chunks in there.
Here is the code that's producing the data blocks

```
<!--begin.rcode echo=FALSE, results='asis', message=FALSE
overLevel <- 0
step <- 10

for(i in seq(1, nrow(exposures), by=step)) {
  tryCatch({
    tmp <- exposures[i:(i+step-1),]
    cols <- ifelse( (as.numeric(gsub(",","",gsub(" ","",tmp$ARExcess)))) >  overLevel, 'tomato', 
                 ifelse(as.numeric(gsub(",","",gsub(" ","",tmp$MTMExcess))) > overLevel, 'lightyellow', 
                 ifelse(as.numeric(gsub(",","",gsub(" ","",tmp$VolumeExcess))) > overLevel, 'azure3', 'white')))

    cat(paste0('<h4><u>Exposures</u></h4>'))
    cat(htmlTable(as.matrix(tmp), col.rgroup = cols, rnames = FALSE))
  },error = function(e) {print(e)})
}

end.rcode-->
```

Comment: I agree on the code, but don't know how to do what you are suggesting, could you help?

Comment: user2554330 why are you calling me a lier?  I inherited this code, I'm not a developer of R stuff, I'm trying to fix it. I realize it's not knitr.  I can't reproduce the code due to problems with the data being on a database.  the issue is I need to see how to loop through the data break it up in chucks of 10 records then produce the Exposures header then continue onto the next records.  I need simple help here not an ass-chewing about how I'm blaming knitr for the problem.  Do you think you could lend some assistance?